# how to establish multi network connections with different IPs in windows

Tags: networking, ip

I know in Linux you can add many network connections with different IPs so you can choose a connection every time according to the the device you want to configure, but is there a way to fo that in windows?

Answer (score 1):

If I am wrong correctly this is what you need.

You can assign multiple IP addresses to an interface.

[advanced-panel-window-ip-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUYpj.jpg)